# Why does the first thing that I print to the serial monitor have whitespace in front of it?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an issue where the first thing that I print to the serial monitor on my Arduino always has whitespace before it. This came simply from running the following code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("BASIC");
}

void loop() {
}
```

[image: Text with whitespace before it]

I was hoping that someone could tell me why this was happening and how to fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: what Arduino board?

Comment: It's an arduino uno